# Improve object.GetType().GetProperties() and PropertyInfo.GetValue(object) performance

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, system.reflection, dynamicmethod

```
private int GenerateKey(T requestParams)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in requestParams.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
            var propertyValue = property.GetValue(requestParams);
            // Do stuff with propertyValue
    }
    // ...
}
```

I have this code snippet that iterates through generic type properties and extracts each property's value. I know that Reflection can be a huge performance bottleneck and that it could be improved using delegates / DynamicMethod / ILGenerator. However its quite difficult for to grasp these. Example on how to utilize one of these methods would be awesome.

Comment: You should bother for this only if you really encounter performance-problems. Doing so [prematurely is poor evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: Does `GenerateKey` method create the same key for the same `T requestParams`?

Comment: @Emrah Süngü yes it does

Comment: @Lemanas can you post a more complete code. And can you mention the use case of your method. Are you going to call this method many times with different instance of same T class? If you are going to use this method only very rarely you do not need to optimize this method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private PropertyInfo[] Properties { get; }
private Func<T, PropertyInfo, object> ExecutableGetter { get; }

public Constructor()
{
      Properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
      Expression<Func<T, PropertyInfo, object>> getter = (tParams, property) => property.GetValue(tParams);
      ExecutableGetter = getter.Compile();
}

private int GenerateKey(T requestParams)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in Properties)
    {
            var propertyValue = ExecutableGetter(requestParams, property);
            // Do stuff with propertyValue
    }
    // ...
}
```

Solution using expression trees / delegates